# Basic jQuery Issues on IE9 (Toggle)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9, toggle

I'm not really a developper. I prefer to design my websites ... So, for my actual project, i must developping some "basic" scripts.

I've met a problem with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("button").click(function toggleDiv(divId) {
$("#"+divId).toggle();
});
;
</script>
```

Into Head-/Head

```
<a href="javascript:toggleDiv('myContent');">LINK</a> 
<div> id="myContent">Lorem Ipsum</div>
```

It works for IE8. (Miracle). But not the others browsers...
The idea is that when u click on "LINK" a windows appears and when you click again, the window close.

Any idea ?

Thanks for u time !

Answer (score 2):

One of the problems is you're mixing two different styles of binding event handlers: one of them is good (the jQuery method), the other is bad (the `javascript:` protocol in your `href` attribute) - the two don't work together in any way. Another problem is that your selector is completely incorrect (it's looking for a button) for the HTML you've provided (you never create a button).

I'd suggest using a HTML5 `data-*` attribute to specify the `id` for the `<div>` on your `<a>` element:

```
<a href="#" data-divid="mycontent">LINK</a>
<div id="mycontent">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

Then use the following jQuery code:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // e refers to the event (the click),
    // calling preventDefault() will stop you following the link
    var divId = $(this).data('divid');
    $('#' + divId).toggle();
});
```

Note that I've used `this` in the above code; what `this` refers to depends on the context in which you use it, but in the context of a jQuery event handler callback function, it will always refer to the element that triggered the event (in this case, your `<a>` element).

Answer (score 0):

If you extract toggleDiv from the handler, it ought to work.  You will probably also need to return false to keep the href from trying to go anywhere.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleDiv(divId) {
        $("#"+divId).toggle();
        return false;
    }
</script>
```